# Apache-poi Java: How can I change the font name and size of a list numbering in a WORD document?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I wrote a method to add numbering to some paragraphs of a word document, however I do not seem to be able to customize the font name and font size of the list numbering (example: a. my item 1, b. my item 2). I am able to customize the font in the paragraphs, however I am not able to customize the font name and font size of the list numbering. Is there anything I might be missing in the code below?

```
    public static BigInteger listNumbering(XWPFDocument doc, BigInteger abstractNumID) {
      CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = CTAbstractNum.Factory.newInstance();
      cTAbstractNum.setAbstractNumId(abstractNumID);

      CTLvl cTLvl = cTAbstractNum.addNewLvl();
      cTLvl.addNewNumFmt().setVal(STNumberFormat.DECIMAL);

      cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("%1.");
      cTLvl.addNewStart().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));

      XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);

      XWPFNumbering numbering = doc.createNumbering();

      abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);

      BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID);

      return numID;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only creates a decimal numbering format for the document and gets the appropriate `NumID`. That `NumID` then needs to be applied to paragraphs in the document which shall be numbered. The format is determined by the paragraphs.

The format of the numbering itself is determined by the paragraph's run properties. Unfortunately there is no method in `XWPFParagraph` to set paragraph run properties until now. So we need using low level `ooxml-schemas` classes to do so. In following code the method `setParagraphRunProperties(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String fontFamily, int fontSize)` is doing this.

The format of the numbered paragraphs is determined by the format of it's  text runs.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTAbstractNum;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTLvl;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STNumberFormat;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordNumberingsFormatted {

 static BigInteger getNewDecimalNumberingId(XWPFDocument document, BigInteger abstractNumID) {
  CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = CTAbstractNum.Factory.newInstance();
  cTAbstractNum.setAbstractNumId(abstractNumID);

  CTLvl cTLvl = cTAbstractNum.addNewLvl();
  cTLvl.addNewNumFmt().setVal(STNumberFormat.DECIMAL);
  cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("%1.");
  cTLvl.addNewStart().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));

  XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);

  XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();

  abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);

  BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID);

  return numID;
 }

 static void setParagraphRunProperties(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String fontFamily, int fontSize) {
  if (!paragraph.getCTP().isSetPPr()) paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr();
  if (!paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().isSetRPr()) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewRPr();
  if (!paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().isSetRFonts()) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().addNewRFonts();
  if (!paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().isSetSz()) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().addNewSz();
  if (!paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().isSetSzCs()) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().addNewSzCs();
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getRFonts().setAscii(fontFamily);
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getRFonts().setHAnsi(fontFamily);
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getSz().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(fontSize*2)); //measurement unit is half pt
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getSzCs().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(fontSize*2)); //measurement unit is half pt
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The paragraph before first numbering:");

  int abstractNumID = 0;

  //get NumID for first decimal numbering
  BigInteger numID = getNewDecimalNumberingId(document, BigInteger.valueOf(abstractNumID++));

  //now apply that NumID to first list
  String fontFamily = "Times New Roman";
  int fontSize = 24;
  //first paragraph
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  //apply NumID
  paragraph.setNumID(numID);
  //set paragraph run properties
  setParagraphRunProperties(paragraph, fontFamily, fontSize);
  //create text runs and format
  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setFontFamily(fontFamily); 
  run.setFontSize(fontSize); 
  run.setText("One");
  //further numbered paragraphs
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setNumID(numID);
  setParagraphRunProperties(paragraph, fontFamily, fontSize);
  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setFontFamily(fontFamily); 
  run.setFontSize(fontSize); 
  run.setText("Two");
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setNumID(numID);
  setParagraphRunProperties(paragraph, fontFamily, fontSize);
  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setFontFamily(fontFamily); 
  run.setFontSize(fontSize); 
  run.setText("Three");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  //get NumID forsecond decimal numbering
  numID = getNewDecimalNumberingId(document, BigInteger.valueOf(abstractNumID++));

  //now apply that NumID to second list having different font
  fontFamily = "Courier New";
  fontSize = 32;
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setNumID(numID);
  setParagraphRunProperties(paragraph, fontFamily, fontSize);
  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setFontFamily(fontFamily); 
  run.setFontSize(fontSize); 
  run.setText("One");
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setNumID(numID);
  setParagraphRunProperties(paragraph, fontFamily, fontSize);
  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setFontFamily(fontFamily); 
  run.setFontSize(fontSize); 
  run.setText("Two");
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setNumID(numID);
  setParagraphRunProperties(paragraph, fontFamily, fontSize);
  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setFontFamily(fontFamily); 
  run.setFontSize(fontSize); 
  run.setText("Three");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordNumberingsFormatted.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

---

For usage with Apache POI 5

Microsoft has changed its XSD which now states that there may be **multiple** font settings and **multiple** size settings in one run property. That's why `XMLBeans` now generates code for `List`s and/or `Array`s of those elements in `CTRPr`: `CTRPr.getRFontsList` now vs. `CTRPr.getRFonts` in past,  `CTRPr.getSzList` now vs. `CTRPr.getSz` in past, ...

So if the need is to check whether `CTRPr` has font settings, one needs to check whether `CTRPr.getRFontsList` returns a `java.util.List<CTFonts>` having `size` greater than 0. And to get the `CTFonts`, one needs to get the first item in that list then. Same for   `java.util.List<CTHpsMeasure>` got from `CTRPr.getSzList`.

See [How to use Low Level CTRPr & CTPPr Classes of latest Apache POI 5.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72067647/how-to-use-low-level-ctrpr-ctppr-classes-of-latest-apache-poi-5-2-2/72075097#72075097) and [Missing method after POI version upgrade from 4.x to 5.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76470221/missing-method-after-poi-version-upgrade-from-4-x-to-5-x/76470498#76470498) for details.

Following needs to be changed in above code to work using Apache POI 5:

```
 // version up to Apache POI 4
 // static void setParagraphRunProperties(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String fontFamily, int fontSize) {
  // if (!paragraph.getCTP().isSetPPr()) paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr();
  // if (!paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().isSetRPr()) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewRPr();
  // if (!paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().isSetRFonts()) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().addNewRFonts();
  // if (!paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().isSetSz()) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().addNewSz();
  // if (!paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().isSetSzCs()) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().addNewSzCs();
  // paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getRFonts().setAscii(fontFamily);
  // paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getRFonts().setHAnsi(fontFamily);
  // paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getSz().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(fontSize*2)); //measurement unit is half pt
  // paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getSzCs().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(fontSize*2)); //measurement unit is half pt
 // }
 // version from Apache POI 5
 static void setParagraphRunProperties(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String fontFamily, int fontSize) {
  if (!paragraph.getCTP().isSetPPr()) paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr();
  if (!paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().isSetRPr()) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewRPr();
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getRFontsList().size() == 0) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().addNewRFonts();
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getSzList().size() == 0) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().addNewSz();
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getSzCsList().size() == 0) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().addNewSzCs();
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getRFontsArray(0).setAscii(fontFamily);
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getRFontsArray(0).setHAnsi(fontFamily);
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getSzArray(0).setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(fontSize*2)); //measurement unit is half pt
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getSzCsArray(0).setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(fontSize*2)); //measurement unit is half pt
 }
```

Comment: The code works correctly. I was able to not only add numbering but also customize the font of the list numbering correctly. Thanks!!