# How to use Low Level CTRPr & CTPPr Classes of latest Apache POI 5.2.2

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi

I am upgrading to latest POI 5.2.2 from POI 3.14. Currently I am using below mentioned low level classes in Apace POI 3.14 which needs to be updated.

i)CTRPr - to set/get run props like bold, italics, etc.. by API's like **getBold(), getI(), etc.. in POI 3.14**, but it seems API's to set/get bold, italics, are changed to handle list of values like **getBList(),getIList(), setBArray(..), setIArray(..), etc.. in latest POI 5.2.2**. Any run would only have 1 RPr in word xml & so API's like getBold() should be sufficient. **Why latest API are utilizing List of values? How to use these latest API's in code & set various Run props ?**

ii)CTPPr - set/get Para level Props of inline paras, list, etc.. using **CTLvl level.getPpr() returns CTPpr Class in POI 3.14**, but **CTLvl level.getPpr() returns CTPPrGeneral class in POI 5.2.2**
eventhough all ParaProps are still present in CTPpr class but **why is CTPPrGeneral class returned instead of CTPpr ? What is use of it ? How to utilise latest API's in code & set various Para props ?**

Any answer with detailed info reg this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Office Open XML`-schemas classes are generated from `XSD` files which are published in  [ECMA-376](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/). They are contained in download part 4. The `XSD`s contain definitions for the `XML` which gets used in `Office Open XML`. [XMLBeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/) from Apache provides methods to auto-generate `Java` classes from this `XSD`s. So the low-level `Office Open XML`-schemas classes of `ooxml-schemas` or `poi-ooxml-lite` or `poi-ooxml-full` do fully translate the given `XSD` definitions to `Java`.

So the general answer to your question about the reason of changes in this `Office Open XML`-schemas classes is that the published `XSD`s have changed from 1st edition in 2006 up to 4th edition in 2012. Or the used `XMLBeans` version has changed and does the `XSD` - `Java` - translation a little bit different.

**`CTRPr` - set/get-methods - one element versus lists**

In 1st edition of `wml.xsd` the `CT_RPr` was defined as a sequence of `EG_RPrContent` where `EG_RPrContent` is a sequence of `EG_RPrBase` having `minOccurs="0"`. This means `EG_RPrBase` doresn't have to occur but can occur. The `EG_RPrBase` then contains all the definitions of the possible run properties. This was interpreted so, that `CT_RPr` might have either none or each of the possible run properties of `EG_RPrBase` **once**.

Now in 4th edition of `wml.xsd` the `CT_RPr` is defined as above but `EG_RPrContent` is a sequence of `EG_RPrBase` having `minOccurs="0"` **and** `maxOccurs="unbounded"`. This means `EG_RPrBase` doresn't have to occur but can occur and if it occurs, then either once or **multiple** times. This can only be interpreted so, that `CT_RPr` might have either none or each of the possible run properties of `EG_RPrBase` even **multiple times**. That's why the lists now.

**`CTLvl.getPpr()` returns `CTPpr` versus `CTPPrGeneral` class**

In 1th edition of `wml.xsd` the `CT_Lvl` element was defined having following sub-element:

```
<xsd:element name="pPr" type="CT_PPr" minOccurs="0">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Numbering Level Associated Paragraph Properties</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

There was not even a definition of `CT_PPrGeneral`. So `CTLvl.getPpr()` **must** return `CTPpr`.

Now in 4th edition of `wml.xsd` the `CT_Lvl` element is defined having following sub-element:

```
<xsd:element name="pPr" type="CT_PPrGeneral" minOccurs="0"/>
```

So `CTLvl.getPpr()` **must** return `CTPPrGeneral` now. But `CTPPrGeneral` provides most possibilities which `CTPpr` also has since also `CT_PPrGeneral` provides most possibilities which `CT_Ppr` also provides except `CT_ParaRPr` and `CT_SectPr`.

And since the 4th edition of `wml.xsd` also still defines the `CT_Ppr` element, `CTPpr` is also needed in `Java`. So `CTPPrGeneral` does not replace `CTPpr` in `Java` since also `CT_PPrGeneral` does not replaces `CT_Ppr` in `XSD`.

Comment: Thanks a lot [Alex Ritcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter). As u had mentioned upon checking XSD, got some ideas. Previously in Scheme any `CT_Ppr` is designed to contain child elements like `CT_ParaRPr` and `CT_SectPr`, etc.. But these values are not possible under `CT_Lvl`, hence in latest schema this seems to be fixed by moving all those common para Pr to `CTPPrBase` wrapped by `CTPPrGeneral` containing specific `CT_ParaRPr` & `CT_SectPr`. So based on context xml being parsed we will get either `CT_PPrGeneral` (or) `CT_Ppr` ? Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @logesh ramasamy: Yes, that is as I would understand it too. But it was Microsoft who defined this and I doubt those who defined this had thought about this as much as you do ;-).

Comment: Thanks a lot [Alex Ritcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter). :-)

Comment: [Alex Ritcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter). I tried modifying MS Word Docx XML & could find that even if set CT_ParaRPr for CTLvl node, word still renders it. But why is that in in latest schemas CT_ParaRPr element has been removed from CTLvl. Why does ECMA Schema structure seems to differ from the Word behaviour ? Also for such docx files it will be issue since we cannot read CT_ParaRPr from CT_Lvl right ?

Comment: Note: Pls check this [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nNMg1fuAjwERBw04QoUpkwmpjUaxWuA8/edit?sp=sharing&ouid=115706912622445080136&rtpof=true&sd=true) for Docx file with CT_ParaRPr added in CT_Lvl which is rendered fine in MS Word.

Comment: @logesh ramasamy: This is tolerancy of the Microsoft Word renderer. Microsoft Word is tolerant enough not to ignore given run properties in paragraph properties of levels, even if that is not defined as such. But Microsoft Word itself never will put run properties in paragraph properties of levels but only in runproperties of levels directly. So your outlined issue is not a such when the file comes from Microsoft Word.

Comment: Okk got it thanks a lot [Alex Ritcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter) :-)