# Missing method after POI version upgrade from 4.x to 5.x

Tags: apache-poi

When I upgraded the POI version from 4.x to 5.x, there was an error that the method was missing；

```
    private static void setHeaderAndFooterXWPFRunStyle(XWPFRun r1, String font, int fontSize) {
        r1.setFontSize(fontSize);
        CTRPr rpr = r1.getCTR().isSetRPr() ? r1.getCTR().getRPr() : r1.getCTR().addNewRPr();
        CTFonts fonts = rpr.isSetRFonts() ? rpr.getRFonts() : rpr.addNewRFonts();
        fonts.setAscii(font);
        fonts.setEastAsia(font);
        fonts.setHAnsi(font);
    }
```

The missing method is isSetRPr() and getRFonts()

```
CTShd cTShd = pr.getShd();
STOnOff.TRUE
```

STOnOff.TRUE and getShd() is also missed

When I change the dependency from 5.x to 4.x, everything works fine

the dependency  of 5.x

```
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-full:5.2.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite:5.2.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:5.1.1'
```

the dependency  of 4.x

```
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:3.1.0'
```

I find ooxml-schemas:1.4 contains these methods but poi-ooxml-full:5.2.3 does not contain these methods

so is there a good solution ？

Answer (score 1):

`CTR.isSetRPr` should further work. I guess you mean `CTRPr.isSetRFonts` which will not work using newest `poi-ooxml-full-*`.  Same for all `CTRPr` - set/isSet/get-methods - one element in past versus lists now.

See [How to use Low Level CTRPr & CTPPr Classes of latest Apache POI 5.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72067647/how-to-use-low-level-ctrpr-ctppr-classes-of-latest-apache-poi-5-2-2/72075097#72075097) for an explanation of the reason for the changes.

In short: Microsoft has changed its XSD which now states that there may be **multiple** font settings and **multiple** shade settings in one run property. That's why `XMLBeans` now generates code for `List`s and/or `Array`s of those elements in `CTRPr`: `CTRPr.getRFontsList` now vs. `CTRPr.getRFonts` in past,  `CTRPr.getShdList` now vs. `CTRPr.getShd` in past, ...

So if the need is to check whether `CTRPr` has font settings, one needs to check whether `CTRPr.getRFontsList` returns a `java.util.List<CTFonts>` having `size` greater than 0. And to get the `CTFonts`, one needs to get the first item in that list then. Same for   `java.util.List<CTShd>` got from `CTRPr.getShdList`.

For the former used `STOnOff.TRUE`/`STOnOff.FALSE`/`STOnOff.ON`/`STOnOff.OFF` `XMLBeans` now generates code which uses `boolean` type (`true`/`false`) directly, if there are only two states possible. So for `CTOnOff.setVal` one now can use `true` or `false` directly instead of `STOnOff.TRUE` or `STOnOff.FALSE` or `STOnOff.ON` or `STOnOff.OFF`.

Unfortunately, no API documentation of all classes automatically generated by `XMLBeans` is publicly available. So if we need it - and if one needs using those classes, one **really** needs it - , we need to download `ooxml-schemas-*-sources.jar` (up to Apache POI 4) or `poi-ooxml-full-*-sources.jar` (since Apache POI 5). Then unzip that and do `javadoc` for  `-subpackages org`. After that we find the API docs in the destination directory. Start reading with `overview-tree.html`.

Comment: thanka a lot Axel Richter.But where can I find references or related literature wihich is about of these changes.Can you go ahead and give me some advice?

Comment: @Tizliu: What references or related literature are you talking about? Are you really expecting Microsoft had explained the changes of their XSDs? Well, no, it hasn't. The only way is to download the different editions of [ECMA-376](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/) and compare.

Comment: Okk got it thanks a lot Axel Richter.